# Struct within a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to understand what doing "equipment kit;" in this code, but without any success. I also tried to find a solution on the internet, and i didn't find.
Here is the code fragment:

```
typedef struct {
    float tank_capacity;
    int tank_psi;
    const char *suit_material;
} equipment;

typedef struct scuba {
    const char *name;
    equipment kit;
} diver;
```

This fragment is from example code in C book.

Comment: It's a struct member of type `equipment` named `kit`

Comment: scuba is a structure, whose one element is a const char and the other is of the user defined struct equipment. Would you add more information of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Luv I'm trying to understand code in book.

Comment: @Andvelop Did the book explain what a `struct` is and how instances of them work? Do you understand how a `struct` with primitive types like `int` and `float` works and is used?

Comment: @user10605163 Books explained all lines except "equipment kit;".

Comment: @Andvelop C gives you basic datatypes like int, char, double, float and their corresponding pointers like char *.  In application you sometimes have to combine these primitive types to describe a real world object. That is when you use struct. For example a struct Person may be described by name, age, social security, address, education and so on. Education here can be a composite value again to be described by another struct which consists of a university name and GPA and so on. In your example scuba can be described by a name and kit which is of type equipment.

Comment: @Luv Well explained. But I'm trying to explain why "equipment kit;" is used in this code, what changes in program, and what will happen if it is not used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `typedef` a struct you do not need to use the keyword `struct` anymore.

So, using the definitions above, you are now able to define data as:

```
struct scuba joe;  // here using "struct"
joe.name = "Joe Carver";
joe.kit.tank_capacity = 30.0;
joe.kit.tank_psi = 70;
joe.kit.suit_material = "neoprene";
```

and

```
diver jane;  // here not using "struct"
jane.name = "Jane Smith";
jane.kit.tank_capacity = 25.0;
jane.kit.tank_psi = 75;
jane.kit.suit_material = "kevlar";
```

the `typedef` just allows the use of a shorter notation. But both `joe` and `jane` are considered of the same type.

Edit: Regarding the `equipment kit` it is a "struct within a struct". By using this approach the scuba driver data describing his equipment gets grouped. This allows better organization of code and data and is considered a best practice.